# Colons not being URL encoded in resource parameters

Tags: angularjs, urlencode, url-encoding, angular-resource

I'm using Angular's Resource module to access a web API, but I'm having problems as the API uses URIs as the primary key.

Whenever I try to make a call to this API, passing in a URI as a string parameter, I'm getting `400 Bad Request` errors. On closer inspection, Resource is escaping all the forward slashes in the URI but not the colon at the start. It's doing a GET on a URL that looks like this: `http://myserver/api/objects/http:%2F%2Fexample.comk%2FmyURI%2F`, which is of course invalid. I've also tried escaping the colon with a backslash, but that doesn't work either.

How can I make Resource escape my parameters properly? I've tried replacing the colon with `%3A` before making the call, but that results in the `%` being encoded again, returning `404 Not Found`.

The service handling Resource looks like this:

```
angular.module('adminApp').factory('MyObject', myObject);

function myObject($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/objects/:uri');
};
```

and I'm calling it like this:

```
MyObject.get({ uri: myUri }, function(result) {
...
});
```

Comment: Did you try adding a backslash before the colon?

Comment: @Voreny Yes, which ends up looking like this: `http://myserver/api/objects/http%5C:%2F%2Fexample.comk%2FmyURI%2F`, so no better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got around this issue by passing the URI as a query parameter instead of as part of the request URL. I did this by changing my resource service to this:

```
angular.module('adminApp').factory('MyObject', myObject);

function myObject($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/objects');
};
```

and leaving the calling code this the same. ngResource then creates a `GET` that looks like `http://myserver/api/objects?uri=http:%2F%2Fexample.comk%2FmyURI%2F`, which is fine.

Basically, if you're using unusual characters in your API parameters, put them in a query string rather than in the URL! :-)